# How to get a array by variable? (Java)

Tags: java, arrays

I have a bunch of Arrays

```
static String[] Laura= {"Female", "Blond"};

static String[] Phil= {"Male", "Brunette"};

static String[] Mark= {"Male", "brown"};


static String[] Person= {"Gender", "Haircolor"};
```

and I want to replace the placeholder person with content from the arrays 2-4, depending on user input.
In short:

I want to acces an array by giving the name as a String that the user inputs and replace my person array.

so something like this:

`person[1] ="Laura"[1]`

I have about 150 different arrays, and having 150 code snippets just for this seems unreasonable to me, there has to be a way. (Its probably really simple I just cant think of it at the moment)

I tried just putting my variable in the place where the Array's name would usually be, but its a Syntax error.

I tried:

`person[1] = variable[1]`

Comment: @JonSkeet Maybe a `Map<String, String[]>`, this being Java.

Comment: Thinking about it more, I suspect you should *probably* actually embrace object orientation more - you probably want a `Map<String, Person>` where the `Person` class would have hair colour, gender etc. Keeping everything in a string array can be a quick way to get started - but gets messy *really* quickly.

Comment: `I have about 150 different arrays` like literally someone typed 150 arrays into your source code?  Clarifying would do wonders here.  What you need to do is to make this into a data file of some sort ("Laura,Female,Blond") then read the whole thing in a loop.  Use Jon's suggestion to create a model object `Person` to hold this data.

Comment: @markspace Yes that someone being me. I broke my code down to make it easier, but seems that made helping me harder! I am writing a "cheat" for Loldle.com, so I have all the 150 Champions in the game and their Traits (gender, melee/ranged, ressource type etc) I am a noob so I figured an array is fine. I'll look into Maps and check it out!

Comment: What you want to use is called associative array.  Associative arrays or maps are built into the languages such as Python, JavaScript, PHP but not Java.  You can use Map to get do something similar.  It's more cumbersome and annoying but you could achieve the same thing.  You can't use [ ] operator.

Answer (score 1):

Variable names do not survive compilation, at least, not in a usable way. Thus, to directly answer your question: **impossible**.

Given that it is, java programmers tend not to do what you're doing. Instead, they'd make a `Map` that maps strings (such as `Laura`) onto values (such as new String[] {"Female", "Blond"}`).

Actually, while we're at it, a java programmer would never store such data in a string array, they'd make types, such as:

```
enum HairColor {
  BROWN, BLONDE, OTHER;
}

enum Gender {
  MALE, FEMALE, OTHER;
}

record Person(Gender gender, HairColor hairColor) {}
```

Then you'd have a `Map<String, Person>` that maps the name of a person (`"Laura"`) to an instance of `Person` representing her.

Then you can do your `person[1] ="Laura"[1]` as:

```
Person p = persons.get("Laura");
```

and go from there. To make this map, you replace:

```
String[] laura = {"Female", "Blonde"};

// with
Map<String, Person> persons = new HashMap<>();
persons.put("Laura", new Person(Gender.FEMALE, HairColor.BLONDE));
```